# Kentico (v10) Scrolling news widget - change US > UK date format

Tags: date-format, kentico

I'm using Kentico CMS v10, and the Scrolling News widget (for Corporate Site). The underlying news articles display with the date in UK format, as per our site culture and user culture, but the "Scrolling News" widget always displays in US date format.

I am guessing I just haven't found the correct place to configure the Culture/TimeZone for this widget... but I cannot find anywhere to do so!

Any ideas gratefully received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I would advise to **NOT** use the default sample elements (if they ever get updated or removed by official upgrade or hotfix it might break your site). I suggest you make a clone of the widget and create your own custom transformation.

Apart from the above in the sample it uses transformation "CorporateSite.Transformations.NewsHome"

[image: Widget properties]

which you can locate in the page type application:

[image: transformation]

here you can update it to a format you please.